# CheckBox inside ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

in sqlserver i have two tables : `'Employee'` and `'PayType'`,
`'PayType'` fields are :

```
 1. PayTypeId  int.
 2. PayTypeName nvarchar(15).
```

and `'Employee'` fileds are:

```
1. EmpId int.
 2. Name  nvarchar(30).
```

Since every Employee can have multiple PayType I add  a filed `'PayTypeIds'` with `nvarchar(50)` datatype that store paytypeids in it - PayTypeId with `','` delimitor-.

In a C# WPF Application I Have Add a listbox :

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstPayType" ItemsSource="{Binding PayTypeList}" Width="194" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Margin="471,314,0,0" Height="86" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox  Content="{Binding PayTypeName}">

                </CheckBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Now my problems are these:

1. How can I use a converter for ischeck property of checkbox to show data from sqlserver
2. How can I send these datas of chekboxes to database

---

Thank you 'RredCat'
Please Assume that we have two employees : `{100,'Joe'} ,{101,'Frank'}`
And Have three PayTypes : `{200,'Hourly'},{201,'Weekly'},{202,'Mounthly'}`

And First emplyoo has two paytypeid so we have : `{100,'joe','200,201'}`
And For second employee: `{101,'Frank','200,201,202'}`

Now with above datas explain to me how can I do with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you use bad approach for this.
What ever.
Create PayType entity with Name and Value properties.
For Employee entity create property `List<PayType> PayTypeList`. Map data from PayTypeIds to this property. Bind listbox to this property without any convertor. Write next code for item:

```
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Seems it is better to use flagged enum for PayTypeIds property.

Comment: but if you have same PayTypes for each user - let me know